# Retrieve data from the same column in two columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL, something like this:

```
ID      NAME
450     China
525     Germany
658     Austria
```

I’d like to query every names where ID < 500 and at the same time where ID > 500 and retrieve the result in two columns using

```
array_to_string(array_agg(NAME),  ',  ').
```

I need the following result:

```
column1 (ID < 500)      column2 (ID > 500)
China                   Germany, Austria
```

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using (`select version();` will tell you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN ID < 500 THEN NAME END, ', ')  AS ID_lt_500,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN ID >= 500 THEN NAME END, ', ') AS ID_gt_500
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you are using a version of Postgres which does not support `STRING_AGG`, then do as you were already doing:

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN ID < 500 THEN NAME END), ', ')  AS ID_lt_500,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(CASE WHEN ID >= 500 THEN NAME END), ', ')  AS ID_gt_500
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: I'm using an older version and string_agg function doesn't work for me.

I tried the following, the 2 columns exists but the aggregate function doesn't work.

array_to_string(array_agg(CASE WHEN ID < 500 THEN NAME END), ', ') AS ID_lt_500,
array_to_string(array_agg(CASE WHEN ID >= 500 THEN NAME END), ', ') AS ID_gt_500

What's wrong?

Comment: Thank you Tim but now it says syntax error at or near filter. I have no idea what's wrong...

Comment: @user6265779 It looks like your version of Postgres does not support either `STRING_AGG` or `FILTER`.  I have updated my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select (select string_agg(name, ', ') 
        from the_table
        where id <= 500) as column1, 
       (select string_agg(name, ', ') 
        from the_table
        where id > 500) as column2;
```

Alternatively:

```
select string_agg(name, ', ') filter (where id <= 500) as column1, 
       string_agg(name, ', ') filter (where id > 500) as column2
from the_table;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/alternatively) doesn't think so.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I stand corrected.  It doesn't appear in Merriam-Webster though, nor have I ever used it in writing.